# Start shell in non-interactive mode with rcfile

Tags: bash, shell, sh

**Background**

I'm building a little thing for speeding up development, basically I got sick of remembering the `foreman run python app.py db migrate` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` etc that modern frameworks force upon me.

It's https://github.com/michaeldfallen/butler.

I'm looking at running the commands in your default shell, since everyone has their own preferences and so that you get access to everything that's usually on your path.

My attempt is here [butler/pull/3](https://github.com/michaeldfallen/butler/pull/3/files#diff-2fc8c7b1f6925508a5481fd370a42678R30).

**Problem**

The problem is that running a shell in non-interactive mode causes it to not run your rcfile (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, etc).

So some commands you'd expect to be able to use might not be there if they are aliases defined in your rcfile, or if they are added to the PATH in your rcfile.

(haven't actually tested the PATH one, might be that since you start bash you are effectively running the shell as a subshell of the current script and so still have access to the path, just an assumption)

**Question**

Is there any way to start a shell in command mode and make it run the rcfile?

If not is there any way of running a command (perhaps in a subshell spawned from the current process) while setting args so that $1, $2, $@ all still work in the commands?

I had tried:

```
execute() {
  local command="$1";shift;
  local args=$@
  set -- $args
  $command
}
```

where the usage is `execute "echo \"Hello, $1 $2!\"" "Michael" "Allen"` but the output was `"Hello, $1 $2!"` so clearly it didn't do the arg substitution.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind still having the output, -i in most shells (i checked bash, csh, zsh, ksh, tcsh ) take -i to mean interactive.

```
<shell> -i <somescript>
```

if you want it in the background put it in a detached screen session (or tmux), optionally make it log to a file if you don't want to recall it but still keep an eye it.

```
screen -dmS <friendly_name> -Logfile <some.log> <shell> -i <somescript>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to start a shell in command mode and make it run the rcfile?

Of course there is. Your rcfiles are just shell scripts like everything else.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Thats not a very reliable way to do it. I would have to make special consideration for every different shell and each persons custom configuration would be significantly likely to break it. And since starting an interactive shell does this and will work well for all users (otherwise they can't use their shell at all) then finding a way to trigger that behaviour seems more future proof.

Comment: @MichaelAllen You never ever mentioned that you need to do this for multiple people whose shell you don't know about. I just answered the question you asked.

Comment: @MichaelAllen Also, "each persons custom configuration would be significantly likely to break it" — not true at all. When you start your interactive shell, it sources your rcs (of course, a sequence of them, defined in the manuals/man pages) exactly as if you explicitly used `source`. So this is no different than starting an interactive shell (if you source the right files).

Answer (score -1):

> The problem is that running a shell in non-interactive mode causes it
>   to not run your rcfile (~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc, etc).

In your `~/.bash_profile`, add the line:

```
[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc
```

(If the user does not have  `~/.bash_profile`, then add it to his  `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`.)

Do similarly for the other shells.

Comment: See his comment below my answer. Apparently he doesn't like `source`/`.`.

Comment: @4ae1e1, as I understood it, he did not want the user to invoke `source` interactively because it depended on the user knowing what he was doing.  I was suggesting here that it be done automatically as per the particular shell's start-up files.  Hopefully, the OP will clarify.

Comment: Well, I think he's writing a script, and I was saying that he can do `source` in that script. "Hopefully, the OP will clarify." Yeah, I don't really know what he wants to do.